# Which version of the serverless framework is compatible with the serverless-aws-alias plugin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless-aws-alias

I'm trying to deploy a serverless yaml file that makes use of the serverless-aws-alias plugin. It used to work (like a couple of years ago) but today, it started erroring out and no matter which combination of versions I test, it fails. Here are a few different scenarios and error messages I face:

```
sls deploy --region us-east-1

 Serverless Warning --------------------------------------
 
  CLI options definitions were upgraded with "type" property (which could be one of "string", "boolean", "multiple"). Below listed plugins do not predefine type for introduced options:
   - AwsAlias for "alias", "verbose"
  
  Please report this issue in plugin issue tracker.
 
Serverless: Configuration warning at 'provider': unrecognized property 'alias'
Serverless:  
Serverless: Learn more about configuration validation here: http://slss.io/configuration-validation
Serverless:  
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
 
 Type Error ----------------------------------------------
 
  TypeError: this.aliasStackGetAliasStackNames(...).mapSeries is not a function
      at AwsAlias.aliasStackLoadAliasTemplates (/home/mehran/Telus/git/solution/repositories/ihsdmdevelopers/commons/sso/server/node_modules/serverless-aws-alias/lib/stackInformation.js:82:4)
      at AwsAlias.tryCatcher (/home/mehran/Telus/git/solution/repositories/ihsdmdevelopers/commons/sso/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/mehran/Telus/git/solution/repositories/ihsdmdevelopers/commons/sso/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (/home/mehran/Telus/git/solution/repositories/ihsdmdevelopers/commons/sso/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
      at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/home/mehran/Telus/git/solution/repositories/ihsdmdevelopers/commons/sso/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:641:10)
      at _drainQueueStep (/home/mehran/Telus/git/solution/repositories/ihsdmdevelopers/commons/sso/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:97:12)
      at _drainQueue (/home/mehran/Telus/git/solution/repositories/ihsdmdevelopers/commons/sso/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
      at Async._drainQueues (/home/mehran/Telus/git/solution/repositories/ihsdmdevelopers/commons/sso/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/mehran/Telus/git/solution/repositories/ihsdmdevelopers/commons/sso/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
 
     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              16.14.2
     Framework Version:         2.72.3 (local)
     Plugin Version:            5.5.4
     SDK Version:               4.3.2
     Components Version:        3.18.2
 
Serverless: Deprecation warning: Resolution of lambda version hashes was improved with better algorithm, which will be used in next major release.
            Switch to it now by setting "provider.lambdaHashingVersion" to "20201221".
            While it is highly encouraged to upgrade to new algorithm, you can still use the old approach by setting "provider.lambdaHashingVersion" to "20200924".
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#LAMBDA_HASHING_VERSION_V2
 
 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
 
  ServerlessError: Export 'Test-dev-ServerlessAliasReference' does not exist.
      at /home/mehran/Telus/git/solution/repositories/ihsdmdevelopers/commons/sso/server/node_modules/serverless/lib/aws/request.js:226:11
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async persistentRequest (/home/mehran/Telus/git/solution/repositories/ihsdmdevelopers/commons/sso/server/node_modules/serverless/lib/aws/request.js:150:14)
 
     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              16.14.2
     Framework Version:         2.72.3 (local)
     Plugin Version:            5.5.4
     SDK Version:               4.3.2
     Components Version:        3.18.2
```

```
sls deploy --region us-east-1

Serverless: Deprecation warning: Local installation of Serverless detected. Starting with next major version, CLI will run it instead of globally installed version.
            Set "enableLocalInstallationFallback" to "true" to switch to new behavior now, set to "false" to keep current behavior and hide this message
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#LOCAL_INSTALLATION_FALLBACK
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
 
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
 
  Export 'Test-dev-ServerlessAliasReference' does not exist.
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              16.14.2
     Framework Version:         1.83.3
     Plugin Version:            3.8.4
     SDK Version:               2.3.2
     Components Version:        2.34.9
```

```
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Preparing alias ...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service Test.zip file to S3 (50.18 MB)...
 
  Error --------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: Unknown object type "asyncfunction"
      at Object._object (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:218:17)
      at Object._function (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:319:14)
      at Object.dispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
      at /usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object._object (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
      at Object._function (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:319:14)
      at Object.dispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
      at /usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object._object (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
      at Object.dispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
      at /usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object._object (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
      at Object.dispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
      at /usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object._object (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
      at Object.dispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
      at /usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object._object (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
      at Object.dispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
      at /usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object._object (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
      at Object.dispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
      at /usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object._object (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
      at Object.dispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
      at /usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object._object (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
      at Object.dispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
      at hash (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:128:10)
      at objectHash (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:33:10)
      at Function.exports.sha1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:44:10)
      at AwsProvider.request (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/provider/awsProvider.js:234:35)
      at AwsDeploy.uploadZipFile (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/deploy/lib/uploadArtifacts.js:76:26)
      at BbPromise.map.concurrency (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/deploy/lib/uploadArtifacts.js:127:21)
      at tryCatcher (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at MappingPromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/map.js:68:38)
      at MappingPromiseArray.PromiseArray._iterate (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:115:31)
      at MappingPromiseArray.init (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:79:10)
      at MappingPromiseArray._asyncInit (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/map.js:37:10)
      at _drainQueueStep (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:97:12)
      at _drainQueue (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
      at Async._drainQueues (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
 
     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              16.14.2
     Framework Version:         1.61.2
     Plugin Version:            3.8.4
     SDK Version:               2.3.2
     Components Core Version:   1.1.2
     Components CLI Version:    1.6.0
```

For the sake of test, I kept the yaml file as simple as possible. Just a single lambda function. BTW, I tested different versions of the serverless since poeple were saying that downgrading was fixing it for them. But for me, no version works. No matter what!

One last thing, if I eliminate the serverless-aws-alias plugin from the yaml file, it will deploy. But I need the alias so I need to make it work with the plugin.

For the sake of completeness, here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1125.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless-aws-alias": "^1.8.0",
    "serverless-prune-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "serverless-pseudo-parameters": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```